# Create Spring Coil

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I want to create spring coil. If I try to create it by manually extruding the edges it will probably look weird and deformed. Is there a way to create a spring coil procedurally so that it is even and symmetrical?

[image]

Comment: @RayMairlot posted question solves my problem.